# Python - numeric class with "don't care" values

Tags: python, numpy, bit

I am trying to create a simple data type to be used as a dtype for a Numpy array, and on which I can perform element wise addition, subtraction, and comparison. The type should take on (at least) three values representing true, false, and "don't care" (DC). The latter is equal to both true and false and behaves like zero in addition and subtraction:

```
>>> MyDtype(True) == MyDtype(DC) == MyDtype(True)    # note reflection
True
>>> MyDtype(False) == MyDtype(DC) == MyDtype(False)  # ditto
True
>>> MyDtype(True) == MyDtype(False)
False
>>> MyDtype(True) - MyDtype(DC) == MyDtype(True)
True
>>> MyDtype(DC) + MyDtype(False) == MyDtype(False)
True
```

I am totally stumped on how to get these semantics in a sane fashion.

Comment: There is no sane way to get these semantics because the semantics are not sane. Equality should be transitive, your desired semantics are not transitive (`M(True) == M(DC)` and `M(DC) == M(False)` but `M(True) != M(False)`). What do you want to use this for? [Perhaps there is a better way](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377).

Comment: Your point about equality being transitive is well-taken: perhaps I should not be using the equality operator at all, and perhaps an instance method would be better. As for what I'm trying to do (ultimately), I am implementing [this paper](http://18.7.29.232/handle/1721.1/6673).

Comment: Maybe you're looking for [3-valued logic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-valued_logic)?

Answer (score 1):

You can use magic functions to control arithmetic operations on objects of your class. You can control even reflected operations, if the object on the left hand side does not implement the respective non-reflected operation.

A comprehensive documentation of magic methods can be found here (The link refers to the arithmetic operator section which is followed by the section about reflective arithmetic operations):
http://www.rafekettler.com/magicmethods.html#numeric

I've had the same problem and wrote a class whose objects are dontcare symbols. It is not exactly what you asked for since it does not wrap values, but it should be easy to adapt it to your needs.
You can get it here:
https://github.com/keepitfree/nicerpython

```
from symbols import dontcare

True == dontcare == True
>>> True
False == dontcare == False
>>> True
True == False
>>> False
True - dontcare == True
>>> True
dontcare + False == False
>>> True
```

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.